# How do I save the funccount from output in fseminf function

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am using fseminf and fmincon functions in my alghoritm. I use it this way

```
[x,fval,exitflag,output,lambda] = fseminf(f,x0,1,@seminfcon1,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub);
```

As an output I get some information:

```
iterations: 5
          funcCount: 21
       lssteplength: 1
           stepsize: 4.9851e-06
          algorithm: 'active-set'
      firstorderopt: 2.9906e-08
    constrviolation: 1.1283e-10
```

I am interested in funcCount, I want to save it. In my other alghoritm I use this in a loop and want to sum all the funcCount that my alghoritm does. In order to do that I need to save at each iteration this funcCount and add it. How can I do that? output(2) for instance does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `output.funcCoun` gives you the current `funcCoun`
- `output.lssteplength` gives you the current `lssteplength`, so on

```
% l is the length of the iteration 
% Initialize an 1D array to store funcCoun
funcCoun_per_iteration = zeros(1,l);

for i = 1:l
   [x,fval,exitflag,output,lambda] = fseminf(f,x0,1,@seminfcon1,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub);
   funcCoun_per_iteration(i) = output.funcCoun;
end
```

To sum them all just use `sum()`

```
Total_funcCoun = sum(funcCoun_per_iteration)
```

But if you really only want the sum no need to store them  you can do it directly as follow

```
% l is the length of the iteration
% Initialize Total_funcCoun to accumulate funcCoun 
Total_funcCoun = 0;

for i = 1:l
[x,fval,exitflag,output,lambda] = fseminf(f,x0,1,@seminfcon1,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub);
Total_funcCoun = Total_funcCoun + output.funcCoun;
end
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!